# Configure Eclipse CDT not to launch external tool on unsuccessfull build

Tags: eclipse-cdt

I am using Eclipse CDT on Linux to create console application. I configured External tool to launch more advanced terminal than internal Console window. Internal Eclipse console does not suit the style of application I am developing. However I can't find a way to configure Eclipse not to launch external tool if the build operation fails. Or other approach would be to remove binary from output folder, but only on unsuccessfull build. I can remove binary before every build to do that, but it would take more time on every launch to re-link. There is a Prompt option in normal Run mode, but i cannot itegrate my Shell script to launch my exterminal there. Advices on achieving such functionality?